# <script> always pending on IE11 and CentOS Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, internet-explorer, javascript

Using Apache HTTPD 2.2.15 on CentOS 6.6

I have a simple client-side call elsewhere:

```
<script src="//txph.cfwebtools.com/CJT/index.js"></script>
```

while returns this code via this machine:

```
function(){}
```

In Chrome and FireFox everything appears to work as intended. However in Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7, the GET seems to never finish and stalls in "(Pending...)". I'm seeing this in the Network tab using F12 Developer Tools.

This works on my local machine using Windows 7 and IIS.

So this seems to be specific to IE11 communicating with Apache.

Side note, I have Adobe ColdFusion 11 installed and if I try calling a .cfm page that generates JavaScript the same thing happens. The MIME type being returned is text/javascript.

The summary shows:

```
Protocol: (Pending...)
Method: GET
Result: (Pending...)
Received: 0 B
Taken: (Pending...)
Initiator: <script>
```

Here's the request headers:

```
Request GET /CJT/index.js HTTP/1.1
Accept  application/javascript, */*;q=0.8
Referer {redacted}
Accept-Language en-US
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    {redacted}
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cookie  {redacted}
```

The response headers are never populated.

The response body is correct showing the anonymous script.

The initiator details:

```
Property    Value
Stage   HTML Preparsing (speculative download)
Element script
Attribute   src
Action  Speculative parsing
Document ID 0
Frame ID    0
Frame URL   {redacted}
Preparser ID    0
Preparser restarted No
```

Any help on why this communication never completely loads is appreciated. Not that other scripts such as this load just fine:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just tried BrowserStack and had a coworker try it. I think this is going to be a local issue and will probably just close this out in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being something specific to my computer and am moving on.